# Why didn't Michelson and Morley assume or conclude that aether is homogenous and permeate all of space?

Tags: reference-frames, experimental-physics, speed-of-light, physical-constants, aether

In the Michelson-Morley experiment, why didn't they assume or conclude that ether is homogeneous and permeate all of space instead of coming from an unspecified source or direction dubbed the ether wind? I mean the signals detected in the interferometer are always cancelled out regardless the relative positions of Earth to the ether wind throughout the year, so can't they also conclude that ether is everywhere too? Maybe they did something to rule out such possibilities but I didn't find that bit of information on YouTube.

Comment: Well, the Earth rotates around the sun, so unless the aether also just happens to rotate with the Earth…

Comment: They didn't assume it because that's what the experiment was *about.*

Comment: "but I didn't find that bit of information on YouTube." A tad annoying at the time they were writing letters worth some 100's USD using pen and paper with a total cost of 1USD instead of sharing clips worth 1USD using equipment worth 100's USD :) ...

Answer (score 40, accepted):

> why didn't they assumed or concluded that ether is homogeneous and permeate all of space

That was the initial assumption.

> instead of coming from an unspecified source or direction dubbed the ether wind?

The idea is that the omnipresent ether should have some frame in which it is at rest.   But the complex motion of the earth relative to the sun suggests that the earth's surface should (at least at some points) be moving relative to that frame.

At any point when the experiment is moving relative to the ether, this should be evident as an "ether wind".   Not a wind due to emission from a particular location, but just of relative motion between the ether and the experimenter.  This would be similar to the "wind" your hand feels when being held out the window of a car moving forward on a calm day.

Comment: The speed of light is the same in every direction to within around $10^{-17}$ of the speed of light. This is a few nanometres a second. See https://journals.aps.org/prd/abstract/10.1103/PhysRevD.80.105011

Comment: @Peter - that is one impressive measurement.

Comment: Of course, this measurement is of the 2 way speed of light (divided by $2$).  Lorentz ether theory is an interesting "alternative" theory, that makes mathematically the same predictions as special relativity, but relies on the one way speed of light not being isotropic, and being reference-frame dependent.

Comment: *omit "divided by 2"

Comment: @Peter We don't actually know that. We can't measure the one-direstion speed of light. It is only ever the back-and-forth speed. We can tell that the back-and-forth speed is the same in different non-parallel directions, though (up to your error bar, of course).

Comment: @Arthur, point accepted. Of course comments can't be edited or I would correct mine.

Comment: @Arthur More generally, you can't measure the one-direction speed of anything unless you have a receiver at the destination with a clock synchronized to the source's clock. Right?

Comment: @JosephRobertJepson If I remember right, Lorentz also never accepted special relativity, and actually developed his eponymous contraction factor in his work on Lorentz ether theory?

Comment: @Idran I don't know if he never accepted special relativity, but yes, he did develop it to reconcile the Michelson-Morley experiment results with the concept of the ether.